# Find the integer integers k for which there exists an integer x

Tags: quadratics, radicals

Find the integer integers k for which there exists an integer x
$\sqrt{39-6\sqrt{12}}+\sqrt{kx(kx+\sqrt{12}+3)}=2k$

So far I haven't advanced much. Removing brackets didn't do anything for me and was pretty bashy.
I am actually lost on this problem, if only the three wasn't in the bracket....Any hint will be well appreciated

Comment: Is there such a thing as a non-integer integer?  What does the repetition mean?  Can you find a minimum value of $k$?  I would just plug in the smallest values of $k$ and see what happens.  It might bring some enlightenment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Isolate $\sqrt{kx(kx+\sqrt{12}+3)}$ on one side of the equation, and square both sides.
After a bit of simplification, you get an equation of the form $A(k,x) + B(k,x) \sqrt{3} = 0$, where $A(k,x)$ and $B(k,x)$ must be integers.  This tells you that $A(k,x)$ and $B(k,x)$ must both be $0$.